# Schema multitenancy in Dropwizard

Tags: java, multi-tenant, dropwizard

Is there a way to implement schema multi tenancy in dropwizard?
The only solution I've found so far is https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/dropwizard-multitenancy but that is using descriminator multi tenancy.

Comment: if you are using jdbi, this might help. http://manikandan-k.github.io/2015/06/04/Multi_tenant_applications_in_jdbi.html

Comment: I am not unfortunately - I am however working on cloning the dropwizard-hibernate project and implementing similar code to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/vD0FgNVGhEw

Answer (score 3):

We basically had the same problem. We wanted to support multi-tenancy, but not only on database level. Different customers have certain services configured differently. In order to avoid passing through the `tenancyId` everywhere, we came up with a custom scope using Guice. This way, every service that is `@TenancyScoped` can get its own predefined configuration or simply the `tenancyId` in its constructor. Then your DAOs can use different schemas based on the `tenancyId`.

It works quite well for us, even though it might not properly scale if you have too many (maybe > 1000, really depends how complex your configuration is) tenants.

I have posted the details about Guice and custom scopes here: [Multi tenancy with Guice Custom Scopes and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308402/multi-tenancy-with-guice-custom-scopes-and-jersey/29352671#29352671).

Comment: How do you select the schema based on the tenancyId, do I have to do that on all of my queries?

Comment: I don't know what you use for your database abstraction. We use mongojack and define the collection/database in the DAOs constructor. This way you don't need to add the `tenanyId` to your queries. I don't know how this can be achieved with e.g. Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I created a multitenant hibernate bundle by modifying the current hibernate bundle code. If you still have the requirement you can check it out.

Here is the link: https://github.com/uditnarayan/dropwizard-hibernate-multitenant/